# Ajax not hitting controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, razor

I have this code here and the alert('test') gets hit but for some reason the .ajax does not. IT does not give me any error and nothing gets passed tot he controller. Ive done this 100 times before and never had this problem. Any reason why? thanks All of the variables have values and such.

tried with the url being   url: '@Url.Action("Add_ICLog_LogEntryRecommendation_Submit", "References")',

```
<div class="card-block" id="RecommendationTypeAddModal">    
        @*@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Log/Investment/Committee/Recommendation/Add/Submit", "References", new AjaxOptions
            {
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = "ICLogRecommendationTypeAddForm",
                HttpMethod = "POST"
            },
                new { @id = "ICLogRecommendationTypeAddForm" }
            ))
            {*@

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ICLogID);

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedIDs);
        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RecommendationTypes)
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RecommendationTypeID, new SelectList(Model.RecommendationTypes, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id="selectedRecommendationType" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Portfolios)
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PortfolioID, new SelectList(Model.Portfolios, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id="selectedPortfolio" })
            </div>
        </div>
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Log/Investment/Committee/Recommendation/Search", "References", new AjaxOptions
        {
            UpdateTargetId = "InvestmentSearchResults",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            HttpMethod = "POST"
        }, new { @id = "InvestmentSearchForm", @style = "flex-grow:1" }))
        {

            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Investments, "Investment Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "m-b-5" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 d-flex">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.InvestmentSearchText, new { @class = "form-control m-r-10" })
                    <button id="InvestorSearchSubmit" data-submitform="true" data-formid="@{ WriteLiteral("InvestmentSearchForm"); } " class="btn btn-info m-r-10">Search</button>

                </div>

            </div>
        }
        <div id="InvestmentSearchResults" />
        @*}*@
        

</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <button class="btn btn-info pull-right" id="addRecommendationType">Add Recommendation Type</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#addRecommendationType").click(function () {

            var recTypeID = $('#selectedRecommendationType').val();
            var portID = $('#selectedPortfolio').val();
            var icLogID = $('#ICLogID').val();
            var investmentID = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').val();
            alert('test');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("Log/Investment/Committee/RecommendationType/Create/Submit", "References")",
                data: { 'icLogID': icLogID, 'recommendationTypeID': recTypeID, 'portfolioID': portID, 'investmentID': investmentID },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {                   
                },
                error: function () {
                    return "error";
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Url is the cause of your problem:

```
url: "@Url.Action("Log/Investment/Committee/RecommendationType/Create/Submit", "References")"
```

change it to :

```
 url:   @{Url.Action("Submit", "References")}
```

Comment: Ive never done that before and it has worked. I tried that and it gave me an error saying i need a ;.

I added that and then it says the , is wrong after it. 

Because the url:   @{Url.Action("Log/Investment/Committee/RecommendationType/Create/Submit", "References")}   returned  blank So This way i dont see working at all.

Comment: try @Html.ActionLink("link text", "actionName", "controllerName" )

Comment: the last one was the exact same as your first answer. and how would actionlink work as the url? 
theres no link.

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("link text", "someaction", "somecontroller", new { id = "123" }, null)
generates:

<a href="/somecontroller/someaction/123">link text</a>
and Url.Action("someaction", "somecontroller", new { id = "123" }) generates:

/somecontroller/someaction/123

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Comment: also try url: "@Url.Action("Log//Investment//Committee//RecommendationType//Create//Submit", "References")"